# Sorting rows with my date column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

```
   date     time  Sno
03-05-2022  12:0   1
03-05-2022  1:30   2
03-06-2021  12:0   22
03-06-2021  1:30   23
03-07-2021  12:0   42
.
.
.
```

I was able to sort `date` column separately as below:

```
['03-05-2021',
 '03-05-2021',
 '04-05-2021',
 '04-05-2021',
 '05-05-2021',
 '05-05-2021',
 '06-05-2021',
 '06-05-2021',
  .
  .
  .
```

using this python code:

```
from datetime import datetime
days_sorted = sorted(train.date, key=lambda day: datetime.strptime(day, "%d-%m-%Y"))
days_sorted
```

I need to arrange my `time` column and `Sno` column also when `date` column is sorted. How to achieve this?

**Desired result:**

```
   date     time  Sno
03-05-2022  12:0   1
03-05-2022  1:30   2
04-05-2021  12:0   3
04-05-2021  1:30   4
05-05-2021  12:0   5
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case doing `sort_values`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] ,format = "%d-%m-%Y")
df.sort_values('date',inplace=True)
```